# Data can see while scrolling in google visualizatio table sticky table headers

Tags: css, google-visualization

I have a google visualization table with sticky headers. But when user scroll the table rows are visible as in the image. This happens in  Chrome browser.

```
var options=null;
if(data.getNumberOfRows()>7){
    options = {
            width : '100%',
            /*height:'460px',*/
            height:height,
            sort : 'enable',
            sortColumn : 1,
            sortAscending : false,
            scrollLeftStartPosition : 50,
            showRowNumber : true,
            allowHtml :true
    };
} else{
    options = {
            width : '100%',
            sort : 'enable',
            sortColumn : 1,
            sortAscending : false,
            scrollLeftStartPosition : 50,
            showRowNumber : true,
            allowHtml :true

    };
}
```

I tried with  increasing table header  line height, margin-top and padding- top with no success.

```
#Table th{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 944; 
    background-color: #e6ecff;
    background: linear-gradient( #ffffff, #e6e6ff );
   }
```

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.